# Robot Framework: Issue finding and clicking elements after opening and switching to the new tab

Tags: robotframework

After Switching the tab (works perfect!), I am not able to find anything on the new tab and I am not able to continue my test. Anyone has any ideas please ?

Test case 1

```
Click Element   //*[@id="tabIndex1"]/div[2]/div[2]   
Sleep           3 seconds
@{WindowHandles}      Get Window Handles
Switch Window   ${WindowHandles}[1]
Sleep       1
Switch Window   ${WindowHandles}[0]
Sleep       1
Switch Window   ${WindowHandles}[1]
Sleep       1
Wait Until Page Contains Element           //*[@id="element1"]
Click Element           //*[@id="element1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following :

Switch window | title=abc

where, abc is the title of the particular new page opened, you can get the title by inspecting